# How do I get values by date using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am trying to use python to deal with time series netCDF4 data. In the dataset, there is one number and three variables for each year, and I want to get numbers of variable A for the first ten years. I have no idea what to do next after I defined time ... Can someone please help me with it or give me some hints? I searched codes for panda, xarray, and netCDF4 but it only makes me more confused. :((

```
time = np.arange(2000, 2101, 1)
```

> This is how I define time

Comment: How do you open the netCDF file, what have you done beside this one line `time = ...`? I mean if you want only the first ten years of data, you can do: `with xr.open_dataset(your_file) as f: data = f.variables['A'][0:10].load().values`. This will load first 10 values of variable A from file.

Comment: I also use `lat = data.variables['LAT'][:]
lon = data.variables['LON'][75:346]
a = data.variables['a'][0,:,:]` to open my code, variable A is a 2d array

Comment: With `...['LAT'][:]` you select all the latitude values, with `...['LON'][76:345]`, you select only part of the longitude values and with `...['a'][0,:,:]` you select the first time moment and all the values along latitude and longitude... So yes, the data of `a` is 2D field.